Connecting Power BI to data in the Dataverse created in Power Apps (Teams)
Using the Teams version of Power App, I created a few tables within my organization's Team's dataverse.  I now would like to user Power BI to report on those tables.
When I go into Power BI, I choose the Dataverse button in the tool bar

and in the list under Dataverse is my team that I created the Power App under

when I expand that option I get the following error...

DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: A network-related or
instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
Could not open a connection to SQL Server) Details:
DataSourceKind=CommonDataService
DataSourcePath= {removed}.dynamics.com
Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
ErrorCode=-2146232060
Number=53
Class=20

Any ideas on why I am getting that message would be very helpful.  I don't have access to the SQL Server so I need to know what to request if it is a configuration issue.
Thanks!!
